Is there a more elegant way to get the time in seconds in a ROS 2 node? (taken over from ROS Answers)
While I was looking for a way to convert an rclpy.Duration object to it's equivalent in seconds, I came across this OP from ROS-Answers: https://answers.ros.org/question/415959/is-there-a-more-elegant-way-to-get-the-time-in-seconds-in-a-ros-2-node/

It seems that the rclpy.Duration() object only has a nanoseconds API. However, to get seconds from an rclpy.Duration() object, we can leverage the to_msg() API from rclpy.Duration() and then use the sec interface like so:
import rclpy

node = rclpy.create_node("my_node")
t1 = node.get_clock().now()
# Do something here that takes some time.
t2 = node.get_clock().now()
time_diff_in_sec = (t2 - t1).to_msg().sec

